# Declaring a new instance of a class in C#

Tags: c#, reference, unity-game-engine

Unity is not liking this and upon research and a warning from unity

("You are trying to create a MonoBehavior using the 'new' keyword. This is not allowed. MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all.)

I know of AddComponent, but I don't quite think that's what I want.

```
public Boids boids = new Boids();
```

Boids is my 2nd class. I saw this work on a tutorial, so I'm kind of confused on why this doesn't work in Monodevelop.

Comment: does the class `Boids` actually use any methods or other things inherited from MonoBehaviour? Why don't you just inherit from `ScriptableObject`? That way it should still be editable in the inspector.

Comment: Yes I did hear about ScriptableObject but I am very confused on how to implement it. I google'd it and did not get any luck, would you be so kind to just write an example line?

Comment: For instance, this (http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CreateScriptableObjectAsset) example does not really help me. I tried for my Boids class to inherit from ScriptableObject instead of MonoBehaviour. But no luck in my inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy to google...

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/119537-You-are-trying-to-create-a-MonoBehaviour-using-the-new-keyword

It's to do with what Boids inherits.  New is apparently not the correct way to instantiate the object, it should be instatiated using the unity framework

```
gameObject.AddComponent<Boids>()
```

Comment: Right and I did google that. Except I need it to be in my globals since I need to access that in my other class. You can't do that in the globals which is why I'm asking SO :) Thanks.

Comment: What I am trying to do is set my "public Boids boids.." to my Boids.cs script in my globals. I need it to have a dropdown in my inspector that contains all my globals for my Boids.cs class. Like in the tutorial I found this on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FXCHdPA_Mk if you skip to around minute 35 he's in Unity and you see what I mean.

Comment: The video is less than 35 minutes long :).  I think you're going to find that you'll need to declare the variable in your globals and initialise that variable at a point where you have a game component with which to call AddComponent.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're quite understanding my question. AddComponent does not help me. I need to reference this script when declaring my Boids class variable (boids). This will allow me to use Boids class inside of my AI class. I can't do that with AddComponent, that simply just adds the script to my gameobject which i don't want to do.

Comment: My question is what the equivalent of new is in Unity. I heard about ScriptableObject but it's kind of confusing.

Comment: What's your question? There's no "equivalent of new" for MonoBehaviours since you just can't use a constructor. What do you want to do? Do your Boids class really need to inherit from MonoBehaviour?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to have a reference to the Boids object? Like `public Boids boids = new Boids();` and then use the variable `boids` to something?

Comment: Roberto, yes to your second comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need your AI script to get all the Boid instances in the scene and do something with them.

If this is the case, then there are multiple ways of doing this, a simple way would be:

1. Have a `public Boids[] boids` field declared in your AI script
2. Create a single game object and add your AI script
3. Create a bunch of game objects and add the Boids script to them in the Unity editor
4. Select the game object that contains your AI script. You should see a boids field in the inspector. Drag and drop all your Boid game objects to that field
5. You can now access all the linked Boids in your AI script

Here is some example scripts:

```
public class AI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Boid[] boids;

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (Boid boid in this.boids)
        {
            // Do something with boid
        }
    }
}

public class Boid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float searchRadius;
    // Anything else
}
```